# What are the reasonable properties of p-value combination methods when all p-values are the same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, meta-analysis, combining-p-values

Suppose we are testing a null hypothesis $H_0$, by combining evidence from $n$ independent tests, using a *p*-value combination method $M$. The combined *p*-value is $M(p_1,...,p_n)$. Assume the extreme case when we get the same *p*-value from all individual tests, which of the following properties of $M$ are more reasonable:

1. $M_n(p,...,p)\leq p$;
2. $M_n(p,...,p)\geq p$;
3. $M_n(p,...,p)$ decreases with $n$;
4. $M_n(p,...,p)$ increases with $n$;
5. all of the above depends on the value of $p$.

Take the Fisher's combination method as an example: $$M_n(p,...,p)=P\{\chi^2_{2n}>-2n \ln(p)\}\approx P\{Z>-\sqrt{2n}\ln(p)-\sqrt{2n}\}.$$The combined *p*-value decreases when $p<e^{-1}=0.367$.

At the same time, with the minimum $p$-value method, $$M_n(p,...,p)=P\{U_{(1)} < p\}=1-(1-p)^n,$$ which always increases with $n$.

In this special case of $p_i=p$, which method is more "reasonable"?

Comment: Is this a verbatim copy of a question from some test or assignment?

Comment: Of course it's not

Comment: Okay, sorry for suspicion. +1.

Comment: @Amoeba It would nevertheless make a great question to ask of anyone who is learning about p-values.  One could add some other interesting possibilities, such as (6) it depends on the particular test; (7) it depends on the null and alternative hypotheses; and (8) it depends on whether the test is two-sided or one-sided.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly most of the theoretical work on meta-analysis of significance values is quite old. One important source is
an article by [Birnbaum, 1954, Combining Independent Tests of Significance](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1954.10483521)
and I think his abstract is worth quoting in full.

> It is shown that no single method of combining independent tests of significance is optimal in general, and hence that the kinds of tests to be combined should be considered in selecting a method of combination. A number of proposed methods of combination are applied to a particular common testing problem. It is shown that for such problems Fisher's method and a method proposed by Tippett have an optimal property.

Those two methods are of course the two you mention.

Two other sources which might shed some light are a paper by Cousins in [ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2209) (Annotated Bibliography of Some Papers on Combining Significances or p-values, 2007) and a simulation study by [Loughin](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947303002950) (Annotated Bibliography of Some Papers on Combining Significances or p-values, 2004).
There is also a 1958 paper which I have not read by T Lipták called *On the combination of independent tests* in a Hungarian journal which examines the problem from an even more general angle or so I understand from secondary sources.

Comment: +1. I took the liberty to insert paper titles and to format the link.